# Why do programming languages round down until .6?

Tags: math, language-agnostic, floating-point, rounding

If you put a decimal in a format where has to be rounded to the nearest 10th, and it is: 1.55, it'll round to 1.5. 1.56 will then round to 1.6. In school I recall learning that you round up when you reach five, and down if it's 4 or below. Why is it different in Python, et al.

Here's a code example for Python 2.6x (whatever the latest version is)

```
'{0:01.2f}'.format(5.555)  # This will return '5.55'
```

After trying some of the examples provided, I realized something even more confusing:

```
'{0:01.1f}'.format(5.55)  # This will return '5.5'
# But then
'{0:01.1f}'.format(1.55)  # This will return '1.6'
```

Why the difference when using 1.55 vs 5.55. Both are typed as literals (so floats)

Comment: I'm not aware of any computer language doing that.  Do have example code at hand of this happening?

Comment: That's because "1.55" converted to a representable binary floating-point number on your system is just *bigger* than the decimal value 1.55, so it rounds up; "5.55" converts to a floating-point number that's just *smaller* than 5.55, so it rounds down.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

First off, in most languages an undecorated constant like "1.55" is treated as a double precision value.  However, 1.55 is not exactly representable as double precision value, because it doesn't have a terminating representation in binary.  This causes many curious behaviors, but one effect is that when you type 1.55, you don't actually get the value that's exactly halfway between 1.5 and 1.6.

In binary, the decimal number 1.55 is:

```
1.10001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100...
```

When you type "1.55", this value actually gets rounded to the nearest representable double-precision value (on many systems... but there are exceptions, which I'll get to).  This value is:

```
1.1000110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001101
```

which is slightly *larger* than 1.55; in decimal, it's exactly:

```
1.5500000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125
```

So, when asked to round this value to a single digit after the decimal place, it will round *up* to 1.6.  This is why most of the commenters have said that they can't duplicate the behavior that you're seeing.

**But wait,** on your system, "1.55" rounded *down*, not up.  What's going on?

It could be a few different things, but the most likely is that you're on a platform (probably Windows), that defaults to doing floating-point arithmetic using x87 instructions, which use a different (80-bit) internal format.  In the 80-bit format, 1.55 has the value:

```
1.100011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110
```

which is slightly *smaller* than 1.55; in decimal, this number is:

```
1.54999999999999999995663191310057982263970188796520233154296875
```

Because it is just smaller than 1.55, it rounds *down* when it is rounded to one digit after the decimal point, giving the result "1.5" that you're observing.

**FWIW:** in most programming languages, the default rounding mode is actually "round to nearest, ties to even".  It's just that when you specify fractional values in decimal, you'll almost never hit an exact halfway case, so it can be hard for a layperson to observe this.  You can see it, though, if you look at how "1.5" is rounded to zero digits:

```
>>> "%.0f" % 0.5
'0'
>>> "%.0f" % 1.5
'2'
```

Note that both values round to *even* numbers; neither rounds to "1".

**Edit:** in your revised question, you seem to have switched to a different python interpreter, on which floating-point is done in the IEEE754 double type, not the x87 80bit type.  Thus, "1.55" rounds *up*, as in my first example, but "5.55" converts to the following binary floating-point value:

```
101.10001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011
```

which is exactly:

```
5.54999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875
```

in decimal; since this is *smaller* than 5.55, it rounds *down*.

Comment: `"%.0f" % 0.5` returns `'1'` for me on Python 2.5.

Comment: Dave: Interesting -- on Python 2.5.1 here it returns '0' for me, too.  What platform are you on?

Comment: I believe that the python "%.0f" just invokes your system's C library version of `printf`.  The C standard recommends, but doesn't require, that printf implement IEEE754 correct rounding for `printf` floating-point formatters.  You may be on a system where the library provider has chosen not to do so.

Comment: My verbiage added some confusion as well though. I said "decimal formatting", but the actual type I'm working with is float. This, because I'm just typing literals into the interpreter rather than Decimal('1.55'), so yes it was being represented as a float.

Comment: @Ken - `"%0.f" % 0.5` returns '1' in both ActivePython 2.5.4 on Windows XP and ActivePython 2.6.4 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 5):

There are many ways to round numbers. [You can read more about rounding on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding). The rounding method used in Python is **Round half away from zero** and the rounding method you are describing is more or less the same (at least for positive numbers).

Comment: Isn't the question saying that "Python, et. al." are **not** doing Round half up?  I think the point of the question is Round half up is the most common method and the asker is not seeing that behaviour.  Although in my experience Python and other languages **do** use Round half up which is why I'm puzzled.

Answer (score 2):

Can you give some example code, because that's not the behaviour I see in Python:

```
>>> "%.1f" % 1.54
'1.5'
>>> "%.1f" % 1.55
'1.6'
>>> "%.1f" % 1.56
'1.6'
```

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't appear to be the case.  You're using the "float" string formatter, right?

```
>>> "%0.2f" % 1.55
'1.55'
>>> "%0.1f" % 1.55
'1.6'
>>> "%0.0f" % 1.55
'2'
```

Answer (score 2):

Rounding and truncation is different for every programming language, so your question is probably directly related to Python.

However, [rounding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding) as a practice depends on your methodology.

You also should know that CONVERTING a decimal to a whole number in many programming languages yields different results from actually rounding the number.

**Edit:** Per some of the other posters, it seems that Python does not exhibit the rounding behavior you've described:

```
>>> "%0.2f" % 1.55 
'1.55' 
>>> "%0.1f" % 1.55 
'1.6' 
>>> "%0.0f" % 1.55 
'2'
```

Comment: Weird, it does do what I was saying if you have %0.2f and you go 1.555, you'll get 1.55, but then with %0.1f and 1.55, you get 1.6. So inconsistent.

Comment: That's because "1.555", rounded to binary floating point, is just barely on the *other* side of the decimal 1.555 vs. what happens with 1.55.

Comment: @orokusaki: the consistency of floating point numbers is absolute within their context which is base 2 arithmetic. Base 10 aritmetic maps one-to-one to base 2 in the context of integers but very seldom when it comes to fractions. For example 0.125, 0.25, 0.375, 0.5, 0.625, 0.75 and 0.875 are exactly representable in base 2 because they are sums of combinations of 2^-1, 2^-2 and/or 2^-3. Inconsistent ... not really.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see a reason for the exact behaviour that you are describing. If your numbers are just examples, a similar scenario can be explained by bankers rounding being used:

```
1.5 rounds to 2
2.5 rounds to 2
3.5 rounds to 4
4.5 rounds to 4
```

I.e. a .5 value will be rounded to the nearest even whole number. The reason for this is that rounding a lot of numbers would even out in the long run. If a bank for example is to pay interrest to a million customers, and 10% of them ends up with a .5 cent value to be rounded, the bank would pay out $500 more if the values were rounded up instead.

Another reason for unexpected rounding is the precision of floating point numbers. Most numbers can't be represented exactly, so they are represented by the closest possible approximation. When you think that you have a number that is 1.55, you may actually ending up with a number like 1.54999. Rounding that number to one decimal would of course result in 1.5 rather than 1.6.

Comment: You said that 3.5 rounds to 2 and 5.5 rounds to 4. This is a typo right?

Answer (score 0):

One method to do away with at least one aspect of rounding problems (at least some of the time) is to do some preprocessing. Single and double precision formats can represent all integers exactly from -2^24-1 to 2^24-1 and -2^53-1 to 2^53-1 respectively. What can be done with a real number (with a non-zero fraction part) is to

1. strip off the sign and keep it for later
2. multiply the remaining positive number with 10^(number of decimal places required)
3. add 0.5 if your environment's rounding mode is set to chop (round towards zero)
4. round the number to nearest
5. sprintf the number to a string with 0 decimals in format
6. "manually" format the string according to its length following the sprintf, number of decimal places required, decimal point and sign
7. the string should now contain the exact number

Keep in mind that if the result after step 3 exceeds the range of the specific format (above) your answer will be incorrect.